# PHP Null Handling

Tags: php, null

I'm trying to set up a handler so when i get 0 results it displays a message saying no results found. I sort of have this working but i'm facing 2 issues at the moment.

When i get 0 Results it does display the no results found but it also displays the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /customers/b/6/d/herculesdjs.co.uk/FETCH.PHP on line 74

line 74 is this:

```
$fetch_row = mysqli_query($con,$result);
```

this is the full script minus the connection info. $City is defined by a drop down box. This has been tested and works fine:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
sprintf("SELECT * FROM `SouthYorkshire` WHERE  `city_id` = '%s'",
       preg_replace("[^0-9]","", $city)));


// Handle Null Results.
$fetch_row = mysqli_query($con,$result); 
$numrows = $fetch_row[0]; 
if($numrows==0) 
{ 
echo "<div id=\"NoResults\">";
echo "There are no clubs in this area, Why not come back another day. Know of one in this area? Why not submit it via Contact Us.";
echo "</div>";
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div id=\"Results\">";
echo "<div id=\"theclub\">";
echo "<div class=\"ClubName\">";
echo $row['EstName'];
echo "</div><br>";
echo "<div class=\"Location\">";
echo $row['EstAddress2'];
echo "</div>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div id=\"website\"><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"photos/more-info.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\"/></a> <a href=\"" . $row['EstWebsite'] ."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"photos/visit-website-button.png\" width=\"75\" height=\"25\" /></div></a></div>";
echo "<br>";
}
echo "</div>";`
```

Another issue i'm having is if there are results in the database it doesn't display the Warning. It displays the results found but it also displays the There are no clubs message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably because you already declared `$con` in `$result = mysqli_query($con,...` and you're using it again in `$fetch_row = mysqli_query($con,$result);` remove one.

Comment: Look twice what you're doing! You're feeding the result of `mysqli_query` to `mysqli_query`. That's just wrong.

Comment: Proper user of `mysqli_query()`: `mysqli_query($con,$query);` You are passing it the result set.

Comment: Fred -ii- - Your right it isn't needed, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: deceze - as mentioned in another comment i have only been programming in PHP for about a week. The original code was a suggestion from another forum. I knew it was wrong but didn't no how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goodness knows why you thought that this was the correct way to obtain the number of records returned by your query: it's complete nonsense.

You should get rid of `$fetch_row` and instead use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

```php
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: thank you eggyal this has worked fine. I got the original code via searching on Google. I have only been programming in PHP for about a week. All self taught. I didn't think the other way was right but quite a few people on different forums said do it that way. I don't like to ask questions on here without giving it a go first.

Comment: @MrBBates: Definite kudos for giving it a go first (far too many people don't!) - but I suspect you must have misunderstood the forums and search results that you have previously encountered.  In any event, the PHP documentation is always a good place to lookup how things should be done - it's full of examples and, once you get used to its layout, it's very easy to use and follow.

Comment: i think i did because there's so many query's about NULL results mashes your brain searching through them lol